# Not able to run adb command in Ui Automator

Tags: android, adb, ui-automation

I am not able to run adb command in UI Automator. When I run a adb command using

```
Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb devices");
```

I get the following error:

```
Error executing exec: Command:(adb services), Working Directory null, environment=null
```

I really need to run a adb command in my UI Automator

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure that `adb` is present in `PATH`, and more importantly, in `PATH` as your Java program sees it?

Comment: Yes my PATH variable contains path upto platform-tools in sdk folder which contains the adb.exe

Comment: Try catching an exception (you must have one). Also, how come your error message complaints about `adb services`, but you claim to execute `adb devices`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAutomater script runs in device shell not in system terminal. Try modifying commands to execute in device shell.